# Ready-Only Select

Tags: forms

On select of one dropbox, I have the values of 2 others updating automatically via Ajax/JS. This works, well, but I also want to disable the ability for users to change these values/

I tried setting these two fields to 'disabled', but when I do this - the auto-select values don't save.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing such as read only in select tag. If you want to disallow user from changing the select tag's selected option, then you can disable it and enable it using javascript before the form is submitted.

If you want to disable the select box, then you can use a javascript code to enable it back before the form submits. So on the onsubmit event of the form, you can enable the select box so that its value is also submitted when the form is submitted.

Hope it will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

**Disable** attribute does exist for **select tag** also. Rest of the process is already explained by above answer. By default select box will be disabled with the choosen value, Now add a click event on the submit button to remove disable attribute from select box so its value should post successfully.

Hope it will help!